# Images are too granular

Tags: html, image

What is the reason for the granularity of images in HTML documents?

I have scanned some documents and created corresponding JPEG images with the following properties:
**image size: 2452 x 3508 pixels

resolution: 300x300 ppi

JPEG, RGB**

and included them into an HTML document with: `<img src="image.jpg" height="100%" />`
I have opened the web page on a big monitor and on a notebook.

In both cases the quality of the images is very bad. They are too granular so that the text is difficult to read. Although if you open them in the standard Windows image viewer you can see every small detail.

How to include an image into an HTML document without losing the quality?

Comment: You've scanned them for print resolution. Scan them at 72 dpi or resize them.

Comment: Why are you doing height=100% ?  Try taking that out.

Comment: if your using IE take a look at this http://css-tricks.com/ie-fix-bicubic-scaling-for-images/

Comment: "if your using IE". I want that the page is displayed in the same way on every common browser type (IE, Firefox...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are scanning an image at print quality and displaying it on a screen that usually cannot handle more than 96 DPI at max.

Re-scan the image using a lower DPI setting and don't try to display an 8 Megapixel image in a browser window.

This may seem counter-intuitive to what you wish to accomplish, but its not. You will never get a scanned image to display on a computer screen as if it where print quality. *(Until we all have retina quality displays for monitors)*

Comment: Is it really necessary to rescan them? I have no scanner at home and there are about 20 documents. Diodeus has suggested to resize them. What would be advantage/disadvantage by following his advice?

Comment: You don't need to rescan them - any decent image editor should be able to resize them and to decrease the DPI :)

Comment: @ka3ak No, you do not NEED to rescan them. You can use *Imagemagick* or *The Gimp*, in order to resize them. You would want to resize and possibly also decrease/save with a lesser DPI (such as 72 or 96dpi).

Comment: Yes, I have already figured out that decreasing of DPI isn't enough. The image size should also be changed. Ok, I will do all this with Gimp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `height="100%"` from image tag.

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Then try following line of code <img src="image.jpg" height="3508" />

Comment: I need the attribute value "100%" too ;)

Comment: Having height="100%" causing this issue. Once you remove that, things will start working fine.